# no module named tkinter, when using cx-freeze, even I specified the path of the module

Tags: python, cx-freeze

I have a python script, which I am trying to make it executable using cx-freeze. This is my script.py file

```
 from cx_Freeze import setup,Executable
 import tkinter
 import sys
 import os

 os.environ['TCL_LIBRARY'] = "C:\\Users\\Admin\\Anaconda3\\tcl\\tcl8.6"
 os.environ['TCL_LIBRARY'] = "C:\\Users\\Admin\\Anaconda3\\tcl\\tk8.6"

 includes = []
 excludes = ['tkinter']
 packages = []
 base = "Win32GUI"
 setup(
     name = 'myapp',version = '0.1',description = 'app',author = 'user',
     options = {'build_exe': {'excludes':excludes,'packages':packages}}, 
     executables = [Executable('emetor1.py')]
 )
```

When executed with "python script.py build", the build folder is created with the .exe file. But when I execute the .exe file it gives me "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named tkinter". I put on the os.environ the path of the package, but I still dont understand why it does not recognize it. Please if someone know how to fix this, I would be very thankful.

I am using Windows, and I used "import tkinter" in my main python script. The main python fyle executes normally with the comand python mainprog.py, but the problem is in the .exe file when created by build command.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Excludes means that the package will not be included. I suggest you remove the 'tkinter' from excludes = ['tkinter'] in your setup script.

Edit: Try this setup script:

```
 from cx_Freeze import setup,Executable
 import sys
 import os

 os.environ['TCL_LIBRARY'] = r'C:\Users\Admin\Anaconda3\tcl\tcl8.6'
 os.environ['TK_LIBRARY'] = r'C:\Users\Admin\Anaconda3\tcl\tk8.6'

 includes = []
 include_files = [r"C:\Users\Admin\Anaconda3\DLLs\tcl86t.dll",
             r"C:\Users\Admin\Anaconda3\DLLs\tk86t.dll"]
 packages = []
 base = "Win32GUI"
 setup(
     name = 'myapp',version = '0.1',description = 'app',author = 'user',
     options = {'build_exe': {'includes':includes, 'include-files':include_files,'packages':packages}}, 
     executables = [Executable('emetor1.py', base=base)]
 )
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer .. I removed it from there, but now I get anoter error :  'TK_LIBRARY', I tryed to put the 'tkinter in the includes , but is the same error'

Comment: Check that your paths to TCL and TK libraries are correct. They should go to the python installation location. For example, for me these are: C:\Users\*MY_USERNAME*\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\tcl\tcl8.6 and C:\Users\*MY_USERNAME*\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\tcl\tk8.6

Comment: Try with dlls included, I edited the script in the answer.

Comment: Mr. Chekunov , I thank you very much for your help. I found a solution where I should additionaly copy the tk86t.dll and tcl86t.dll to the build folder together with the main.py file. Again thank you for your time and reply.

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of research, and following the instructions, nothing worked. I checked that I already had the tcl8.6 and tk8.6 files inside lib, but I noticed that the Tkinter folder started with a capital letter and it looked for "tkinter", so I changed the "T" to "t", and amazingly that seems functional.

Answer (score -1):

```
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable
import tkinter
import sys
import os

# Dependencies are automatically detected, but it might need fine tuning.
build_exe_options = {"packages": ["os"], "includes": ["tkinter"],"include_files": ["ico.png"]}


# GUI applications require a different base on Windows (the default is for a
# console application).
base = None
if sys.platform == "win32":
    base = "Win32GUI"

setup(name="merge",
      version="0.1",
      description="My GUI application!",
      options={"build_exe": build_exe_options},
      executables=[Executable("merge.py", base=base)])
```

Had similar issue. This format for ***setup.py*** solved it for me.